# Install pytorch from the source using pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pytorch, remote-server

I am trying to install pytorch on a remote server. It has `CentOS 6.5` and according to [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/14274)
it has stopped support for `CentOS 6`. So, I am trying to install it via [source](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source).

The recommended method to install is by anaconda but the thing is I am getting plenty of issues while installing anaconda as it is messing with the remote server path's alot so I have decided to use pip.
 But I have issues regarding converting some conda commands in pip which are as below-

`conda install -c pytorch magma-cuda90`
The above command is mentioned before the pytorch cloning step and it given me an error that 
`Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pytorch'`
The other issue I am facing is below-
`export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX:-"$(dirname $(which conda))/../"}`
Wht should be the alternative for `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` in pip?

Comment: The other issue I am facing is below-
`export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${CONDA_PREFIX:-"$(dirname $(which conda))/../"}` wdym by that ? Which issue ?

Comment: That I don't know how to convert in pip the above command

Comment: Just updated it.

Comment: This is `conda install -c pytorch magma-cuda90` is only required if you want CUDA support, you can skip it

Comment: I want CUDA support

Comment: Which python version ?

Comment: It is `Python 3.6.5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your Python version, you can try to install from the [wheel](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html) files.

```sh
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torch-1.3.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl   --user # For torch 
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu101/torchvision-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl  --user # For torchvision
```

If it fails you may want to check your glibc version:

```sh
ldd --version
```

because PyTorch is supported on Linux distributions that use glibc >= v2.17.

For your question:

> What should be the alternative for `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in pip ?

[CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html) act as a build directive to indicate where to find modules needed for the build. In your case (installation as non-root with the `--user` flag) it's probably:

`~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages`

You can verify the exact location with the following command:

```sh
python -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])"
```

As a side note your compilation will more likely fail if you still don't have the minimum required version of glibc.

Comment: I have tried this method and I got `    from torch._C import *
ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /nethome/rxs1576/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_C.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)`

Comment: I ran this command `ldd --version` and I hope this gives the libc version and I got `ldd (GNU libc) 2.12` so where I am doing wrong

Comment: But I need pytorch greater than or equal than 1.0 and I have not been able to get it from the above method

Comment: Check [this article](https://serverkurma.com/linux/how-to-update-glibc-newer-version-on-centos-6-x/) on how to upgrade manually glibc

Comment: I don't have the sudo access to the server so I can't install glibc

Comment: Alternatively, because building glibc from source is long and tedious, you can check [How can I install an rpm without being root](https://superuser.com/questions/209808/how-can-i-install-an-rpm-without-being-root) or [rpm without root](https://serverfault.com/questions/100189/rpm-without-root)

Comment: will the same issue of glibc will lie if I moved to installing by conda

Comment: Likely yes, see [this](https://gist.github.com/michaelchughes/85287f1c6f6440c060c3d86b4e7d764b), the first step is to update glibc and libc++ and [this thread](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6607) (the last comment states errors with setup.py